# Swift : Cast from NSArray to unrelated type NSIndexPath Always fails

Tags: ios, swift, nsindexpath

I am casting an NSArray to NSIndexPath so that i can use that in my reloadRowsAtIndexPath, can anyone suggest better solution and why do i get the warning "Cast from NSArray to unrelated type NSIndexPath Always fails" and do i have to be worried about this ?

code

```
let indexArray : NSIndexPath? = NSArray(Objects:NSIndexPAth(forRow: 0, inSection:2)) as? NSIndexPath
self.myTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexArray!], withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely do have to be worried about that, especially because you force unwrap it (with `!`) on the very next line. That warning is telling you that you're casting an `NSArray` to an `NSIndexPath`, and that you can't do that. In other words, `indexArray` will always be `nil`. And because you force unwrap it on the next line, it will always crash.

The reason you're having trouble is because you don't need to cast to `NSIndexPath` at all: `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()` expects an array of index paths, which is what you made, although you could make it much more easily. Here's the simple way to rewrite your code:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection:2)
self.myTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

`[indexPath]` means "an array containing `indexPath`", so that creates the array that `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()` is looking for quite easily. As you can see, no casting is required.

Note that you should use `if let` and other safe unwrapping methods as much as possible--beginners to Swift should pretend that `!` means "please crash now". :)

Comment: The `NSIndexPath` initializer doesn't return an optional, you can't unwrap it.

Comment: Thanks @dan! Fixed.